# GPU Sink Failed in Tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am using tensorflow to make an nlp algorithm that writes Shakespeare. It previously trained for hundreds of epochs without a problem but know it gives the following error:

```
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 in order to run Identity: GPU sync failed [Op:Identity]
```

I have 171312 training examples and I am running with a batch size of 65 on a GTX 1060 3GB with an i7-8700:

```
model.fit(X, y, callbacks=[callback], batch_size=65, epochs=250)
```

It runs for a few thousand examples before the error. The full error message is below:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-bc8f8d194556>", line 1, in <module>
    model.fit(X,y, callbacks=[callback], batch_size=65, epochs=250)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 397, in fit
    prefix='val_')

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 771, in on_epoch
    self.callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 302, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 992, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model(epoch=epoch, logs=logs)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1038, in _save_model
    self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1123, in save_weights
    self._trackable_saver.save(filepath, session=session)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1168, in save
    file_prefix=file_prefix_tensor, object_graph_tensor=object_graph_tensor)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1116, in _save_cached_when_graph_building
    save_op = saver.save(file_prefix)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 230, in save
    sharded_saves.append(saver.save(shard_prefix))

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 69, in save
    tensors.append(spec.tensor)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\saveable_object.py", line 52, in tensor
    return self._tensor() if callable(self._tensor) else self._tensor

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py", line 95, in f
    return array_ops.identity(x)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 267, in identity
    ret = gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3826, in identity
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)

  File "C:\Users\luke_\anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 6606, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 in order to run Identity: GPU sync failed [Op:Identity]
```

Here is the model's code:

```
X, y = shuffle(X, y)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(tok.word_index)+ 1, 100),
                             tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(200, return_sequences=True)),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
                             tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(90),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, activation='relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(tok.word_index) + 1, activation='relu')])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: either you already allot this gpu for other work or else close the setup and release the memory and restart it

Comment: I tried restarting my computer but the same thing happened.